# Push notification not showing when app is in running in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework

I have successfully implement the push notification using (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) in cordova.Everthing works correctly except that push notification is not showing when the app is running(ie foreground).Here is the code

```
case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
        if ( e.foreground )
        {
            // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
            //this is not working
            if(e.foreground){              
                var myMedia = new Media("/assets/www/img/beep.mp3");              
                my_media.play();
            }else{
               // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
            }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
        if (e.foreground) {
            //when you are running the app, you get the alert 
             alert(e.payload.message);


        }
        else {
               //do something for the case where user is not using the app.
                  if (e.coldstart)
                  console.log('--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '');
                 else
                   console.log('--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '');
                 $window.location.href = ('#/bucket/notification');
             }
        break;
```